# How to stop Trogdor testing Agent + Coordinator service responsible for shutting down Kafka and Zookeeper instances

Tags: testing, apache-kafka, performance-testing

I have been running stress testing on Kafka. I used trogdor test framework for creating network and IO faults. After testing I tried to kill process agents but the trogdor is running zombie processes which can't be killed by `kill -9`.

The running trogdor service is killing zookeeper and Kafka instances and my cluster can't be active. What is the way to shutdown these service safely without the need to restart Unix server?

I would also appreciate a way to find parent process responsible for this. I currently have to use `ps -o ppid= <child process name >`

I've tried killing Trogdor process, AgentClient process, agent and coordinator process.

When I try to kill the parent process of any of the above mentioned processes, the connection to SSH server is disconnected and PuTTY is closed.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me to kill the Coordinator and Agent java processes:

```
kill `jps | grep "Coordinator" | cut -d " " -f 1`
kill `jps | grep "Agent" | cut -d " " -f 1`
```